# Dispatching to main queue when I'm already in main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

Tell me if this make sense. This is an iOS question.

I'm seeing code where it is already in the main thread, but the code would dispatch_async all sorts of UI code to the main thread's queue. Layouts, animations etc etc.

I was told this some how speeds up responsiveness (example, when pushing a view controller, you would dispatch other UI ops there so it won't block the push transition.

This doesn't make sense because first it is dangerous, second, it doesn't guarantee when the UI code gets run(even though it will probably run with milliseconds).   The only good reason I can see is for it to guarantee that the UI code is not accidentally run in a different thread.

What do you guys think?

Comment: When would one employ this pattern?

Comment: If you give me a simple example of when it can be used it will be easier than me putting down code i think.  Basically the code you will see is just where we dispatch_async code that contains custom layoutSubview parameters inside.  Others are like dispatching_async a 'Scroll table to top' function.  Why would you need that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are definitely times you employ this pattern of dispatching back to the main queue, so I might not be too quick to dismiss it or label it as "dangerous" (though the way you characterize it, it does sound suspicious). You should share some code samples of how you're seeing this pattern being used, and we can comment further.

When would you dispatch to the main queue? The prototypical example is when you're doing something on a background queue, but then want to dispatch the UI updates back to the main queue, e.g.:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

     // do something time consuming here, like network request or the like

     // when done, update the UI on the main queue:

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         // update the UI here

     });
});
```

But I'm assuming this is not the sort of dispatch to the main queue you're talking about. I'm assuming from your comment where you have something on the main queue dispatching asynchronously right back to the main queue itself.

The reason you would do that is if you don't want the dispatched code to run immediately, but rather to be queued for the next iteration of the run loop. This lets the autorelease pool drain, lets the current method complete (and release any resources it might have been using), lets other dispatched tasks run first, gives the UI a chance to reflect any changes you may have initiated, etc.

A few examples of when some developers might do this include:

1. You might use this pattern if you want a method call itself recursively, but you want to yield back to the run loop, to let resources be freed, let the UI reflect any changes, etc. You're basically saying "ok, let this method finish, but in the next run loop, run this method again."
2. A little more suspect, I've seen this pattern in `viewDidLoad` where you want to give auto layout a chance to "catch up" and update the frames. E.g. there is a common third-party progress indicator that won't work if you just invoke it from `viewDidLoad`, but it works if you dispatch that update back to the main queue.

Having articulated reasons why I've seen developers dispatch back to the main queue from the main queue, itself, I must confess that many of these patterns suffer from code smell and are often better accomplished via different patterns. But these are a few examples that I've seen.

But, again, if you want assistance on your particular code sample, you have to share it with us. We can't tell what the developer intended without seeing the code sample.

Comment: Here is one example persudo code: Inside viewDidAppear, dispatch_async{ mkmapview alloc init, then add this to the subview, then set the map point}   Not sure if this is enough code for you.

Comment: I understanding what you are trying to say, but this seems like a really convoluted way of a memory management of sorts.  The reason is that if you are that tight on memory, there is already something wrong with your app.

Comment: @mskw Adding a subview is not a case where dispatching it back generally makes sense. Maybe the developer was struggling with the fact that he/she wanted access to the `frame`. Hard to say on the basis of this pseudo code. Don't get me wrong: I'm not saying that dispatching back to the main queue is a good idea (because it's generally better solved other ways), but I'm suggesting that it's not necessarily "dangerous", and there are isolated code patterns where it's useful. Doesn't sound like that's the case here, though.

Comment: I'm saying is dangerous because it creates ivar/properties dependency issues.  Say I dispatch a frame change, and the next line of code have logic expecting the frame to update, but the queue runs the frame change after that. Bam, bug caused.

Comment: Also, do you see how this dispatching can speed up responsiveness of UI?  For example a user taps on a Photo that triggers a Navigation push, but inside the next view controller, there is other heavy UI updates that goes on(say photo gallery view layouts).?  For me, I think it could speed up the tap and the instant transition, but if the UI update that was queued was heavy enough it would still cause a stutter if it interrupted the Nav Push transition.

Comment: @mskw I'd be surprised, but just profile it with Instruments and see. Or test it empirically on physical devices. Personally, I have image intensive views is dispatch the retrieval of the `UIImage` objects to a background queue (even when dealing with persistent storage ... on anything but the latest hardware, even that process can result in a discernible stuttering in the UI if done on the main queue) and then dispatch the `UIImageView` updates back to the main queue. But if you're finding that dispatching from main queue back to the main queue improves your responsiveness, then go for it.